# What's the proper way to create a global array constant?

Tags: c#, arrays, global-variables, constants

I have done some searching, but haven't found much. At the moment I am using:

```
class GlobalArrays
{
    public static string[] words = { "Easy", "Medium", "Hard" };
    public static Color[] backColors = { Color.LightGreen, Color.Orange, Color.Red };
}
```

Which works well, but I don't know if it is the correct way to do it. I've seen global variables done like this:

```
static class GlobalVars
{
    const string SOMETHING = "LOL";
}
```

Which is supposedly the Microsoft approved way of declaring namespace level constants, but when I tried that with arrays, it threw an error, saying they could only be of type `string`.

```
static class GlobalArrays
{
    public const string[] words = { "Easy", "Medium", "Hard" };
    public const Color[] backColors = { Color.LightGreen, Color.Orange, Color.Red };
}
```

The above code won't compile, and says they can only be initialized with null, because they are of a type that is not `string`.

Comment: Could you post the code that throws an error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the compiler:

> A const field of a reference type other than string can only be initialized with null.

I think this is about as close as you're going to get:

```
private static readonly string[] words = { "Easy", "Medium", "Hard" };
public static IReadOnlyCollection<string> Words
{
    get
    {
        return Array.AsReadOnly(words);
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that the values of array elements can still be changed individually by any method that can access it.

Comment: @shree.pat18 That's why I've hidden it behind a ReadOnlyCollection.